# how to call af:popup after jspx page load?

Tags: javascript, java, oracle-adf

I have a JSPX page and am using ADF rich components on it.

I have an ADF popup, and I want to show this pop up when the page is loaded
for the first time (it shouldn't show up again when the page is refreshed)

How can this be achieved?

This is the structure of the page:

```
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.1"

      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich"
      xmlns:pe="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/pageeditor"
      xmlns:cust="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/customizable"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">   

<af:popup id="notiPopupId" rendered="#{homeBean.isThereNotif}" clientComponent="true" binding="#{homeBean.notificationsPopUp}">

<af:dialog id="notiDialogId" styleClass="message_dialog" type="none"
           title="#{portalBundle.notifications}" contentWidth="400"
           closeIconVisible="true">
<af:outputText value="my output message" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create class that implements `PagePhaseListener` 
and override below methods
,something like that :

```
public void beforePhase(PagePhaseEvent phaseEvent) {
    UIViewRoot viewRoot = JSFUtils.getRootView2();
    if (!AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isPostback()) {
        if (phaseEvent.getPhaseId() == Lifecycle.PREPARE_RENDER_ID) {
            if (viewRoot != null) {
                String curPage = viewRoot.getViewId();
                try {
                    if (curPage != null) {
                        // call Pop Up programmatic here
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public void afterPhase(PagePhaseEvent pagePhaseEvent) {

}

public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
    return PhaseId.RESTORE_VIEW;
}
```